# Manipulação MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Estou usando o moment.js para validar algumas datas e utilizei a função `moment().weeksInYear()` para verificar em qual semana do ano estamos.

Preciso fazer uma previsão de data, após o usuário me informar uma data, eu consigo calcular quantas semanas irão se passar e somo isto na função do moment por incremento `moment().weeksInYear() + semanas`.

Eu preciso manipular o moment de forma que eu descubra qual será a sexta feira da semana que eu calcular.

exemplo:

```
moment().weeksInYear() // retorna semana 52 
moment().weeksInYear() + semanas // retorna 54
```

preciso usar este `54` para saber a data exata da sexta feira da semana `54` do ano.

Comment: Um ano não tem 54 semanas, esse cálculo está errado. Você quer pegar a sexta-feira da segunda semana do ano seguinte. Precisa verificar se a soma das semanas é maior que a quantidade de semanas no ano, se for, somar **+1** ao ano atual. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode obter o [dia da semana pelo nome](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/), no caso: *friday*.

```js
// obtendo o número da semana atual (no seu caso, é a soma das semanas).
var week = moment().week();

// obtendo a sexta-feira daquela semana e convertendo em data.
var friday = moment().day('friday').week(week).toDate().toString();

console.log(friday);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Deu Certo, Obrigado! :D